# Mysql в Mac OS Sierra

Tags: mysql, macos, mac, sierra

Раньше никогда не было проблем с этим, а когда обновился - перестал работать mysql. Переустановил - не помогло. Выдает такую ошибку

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

Перечитал кучу всего, но так и не смог решить проблему. Может кто то уже такое исправлял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй в файл my.cnf добавить эту строку

```
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Если папки */var/run/mysqld* нет то нужно её создать и проверить чтобы у mysql были права туда писать, сделать это можно тремя командами из терминала

```
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```